# bootstrap navigation in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I had previous navigation tree, as shown below:

```
<?php               
          $main=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainmenu WHERE aktif='Y'");

          while($r=mysql_fetch_array($main)){
             echo "<li><a href='$r[link]'><span>$r[nama_menu]</span></a>";
             $sub=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu, mainmenu  
                        WHERE submenu.id_main=mainmenu.id_main 
                        AND submenu.id_main=$r[id_main] AND submenu.id_submain=0 AND submenu.aktif='Y'");
           $jml=mysql_num_rows($sub);
            // if submenu found                
            if ($jml > 0){
              echo "<div><ul>";                 
                while($w=mysql_fetch_array($sub)){
                echo "<li><a href='$w[link_sub]' class='parent'><span>&#187; $w[nama_sub]</span></a>";
                      $sub2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE id_submain=$w[id_sub] AND id_submain!=0");
                $jml2=mysql_num_rows($sub2);
                if ($jml2 > 0){
                              echo "<div><ul>";
                         while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sub2)){
                            echo "<li><a href='$s[link_sub]'>&#187; $s[nama_sub]</a></li>";
                         }
                        echo "</ul></div></li>";
                      }
                }           

             echo "</li></ul></div>
                   </li>";
            }
            else{
              echo "</li>";
            }
          }        
        ?>
```

then I also have a database, as follows:

[SQL](http://pastebin.com/hgqeU7Na)

How to convert the navigation tree into bootstrap?
thank in advance

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Please paste the rendered HTML since we do not know the actual output and how exactly it's related/not-related to Bootstrap.

Comment: I mean, I found it hard on how to realize the concept of the menu that I have into the bootstrap navigation,
by the way thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to suite bootstrap

**Bootstrap Markup for Navigation**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>           
 </ul>
```

**Here is php code**

```
$main=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainmenu WHERE aktif='Y'");

      while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($main)) {

$sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu, mainmenu  
                    WHERE submenu.id_main=mainmenu.id_main 
                    AND submenu.id_main=$r[id_main] AND submenu.id_submain=0 AND submenu.aktif='Y'");
$jml = mysql_num_rows($sub);

$dropdown = ($jml > 0) ? 'class="dropdown"' : ''; 
echo "<li $dropdown><a href='$r[link]'>$r[nama_menu]";

// if submenu found
if ($jml > 0) {
    echo "<b class="caret"></b><ul class="dropdown">";
    while ($w = mysql_fetch_array($sub))
        {
        echo "<li><a href='$w[link_sub]' class='parent'><span>&#187; $w[nama_sub]</a>";
        $sub2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE id_submain=$w[id_sub] AND id_submain!=0");
        $jml2 = mysql_num_rows($sub2);
        if ($jml2 > 0)
            {
            echo "<ul $dropdown>";
            while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sub2))
                {
                echo "<li><a href='$s[link_sub]'>&#187; $s[nama_sub]</a></li>";
                }

            echo "</ul></li>";
            }
        }

    echo "</li></ul>
               </li>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "</a></li>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion
 So far  this concept  are still obstacles on the "dropdown",  because the main menu also has a link, and this seems more suited to the method "on mouse over" instead of "click"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 3, you can create a new custom css file and add this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
```

}